# Proof that a murder took place using Prolog

Tags: prolog, resolution, proof

The task:

> You come to a crime scene. There you see a broken window, a bloodied
> ax and a corpse. A suspect was arrested 100 meters from the house. You
> are in the courtroom and have to prove to the judge that a murder took
> place. A murder has occurred when a body, a burglary site, a murder
> tool, and a suspect are found.
>
> Rewrite the above statements in Prolog predicates and facts in such a
> way that you can use them to prove by contradiction and resolution
> that a murder took place.

Here is my knowledge base:

```
brokenWindow. 
bloodiedAx.
corpse.
suspect.

murderTool(bloodiedAx).
burglarySite(brokenWindow).
body(corpse).

murder :- 
        body(X),
        burglarySite(Y),
        murderTool(Z),
        suspect.
```

Output:

```
?- murder.
true
-> Singleton variables: [X,Y,Z]
```

Is this correct? Also, can somebody point me towards an explanation on how to do proofs by contradiction and resolution?

Comment: That's a really bizarre exercise. In a sense it demands that you write an (not so complex) [Complex Event Processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) that scans for events of _body_ + _burglary site_ + _murder tool_ + _suspect_ and emits the indication that "murder has occurred" when it sees those. So... looks ok to me though I don't see the point.

Comment: To be honest, me neither. Especially since all our previous tasks were about lists.

Comment: Well, lists are just one distinguished way of arranging data ... SWI-Prolog adds the dict (or one can use library(assoc)) These should probably appear in a course, too.

Comment: Regardin the "proofs by contradiction and resolution", that's what Prolog does, or at least that's what one can consider what it does when one stays in a purely logical subset (no calls, cuts, I/O, metapredicates). It performs [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) on the clause augmented with the negation of the goal, trying to do a "proof by contradiction". I suppose you are being asked to do such a proof by hand. Of course, Prolog doesn't _really_ do that and I don't think anybody thinks that way when programming.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer can you point me towards an explanation on how to do such proofs ?

Comment: From "Logic Programming with Strong Negation" (David Pearce, Gerd Wagner, FU Berlin, 1991): _According to the standard view, a logic program is a set of definite Horn clauses. Thus, logic programs are regarded as syntactically restricted first-order theories within the framework of classical logic. Correspondingly, the proof theory of logic programs is considered as the specialized version of classical resolution, known as SLD-resolution._...

Comment: _This view, however, neglects the fact that a program clause, a_0 <— a_1, a_2, • • •, a_n, is an expression of a fragment of positive logic (a subsystem of intuitionistic logic) rather than an implicational formula of classical logic. The classical interpretation of logic programs, therefore, seems to be a semantical overkill._

Comment: _It should be clear that in order to explain the deduction mechanism of Prolog one does not have to refer to the indirect method of SLD-resolution which checks for the refutability of the contrary. It is certainly more natural to view Prolog's proof procedure as a kind of natural deduction, as, for example, in [Hallnäs & Schroeder-Heister 1987] and [Miller 1989]. This also is more in line with the intuitions of a Prolog programmer. Since Prolog is the paradigm, logic programming semantics should take it as a point of departure._

Comment: For example, here: https://aic.ai.wu.ac.at/~polleres/teaching/lma2006/lecture8.pdf but you should have a textbook somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Actually they didn't recommend any textbook.

Comment: Here is another one on Resolution: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-automated/#Res

Comment: this is at best a joke, nothing to do with Prolog or programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

**First:** Write the facts.

```
evidence('broken_window').
evidence('bloodied_axe').
evidence('corpse').
evidence('suspect').
```

**Second:** Write the predicate courtProof which will take zero arguments. The predicate will use findall to find all the available evidences. It will save all the available evidences in the list EvidenceList.

```
findall(A,evidence(A),EvidenceList),
```

**Third:** Using if-else you check that if all the things are available it means there is enough proof to prove that a murder took place, else, not enough proof. **member** will check if a certain evidence is present in the list or not.

```
    (   member('broken_window',EvidenceList),member('bloodied_axe',EvidenceList),
member('corpse',EvidenceList),member('suspect',EvidenceList)->  
        write('Enough Proof!'); write('Not Enough Proof!')).
```

**Fourth:** Putting the code together.

```
evidence('broken_window').
evidence('bloodied_axe').
evidence('corpse').
evidence('suspect').

    courtProof:-
        findall(A,evidence(A),EvidenceList),
        (   member('broken_window',EvidenceList),member('bloodied_axe',EvidenceList),
member('corpse',EvidenceList),member('suspect',EvidenceList)->  
        write('Enough Proof!'); write('Not Enough Proof!')).
```

**Example:**
Lets say in facts I only have 3 evidences **(Contradiction (Not Goal): It can only be proven that a murder has taken place when all 4 have occurred, but here we have only 3)**, then:

```
evidence('broken_window').
evidence('bloodied_axe').
%evidence('corpse').    %Corpse not discovered yet.
evidence('suspect').

?- courtProof.
Not Enough Proof!
1true
```

Now I have all evidences **(Resolution (Goal): All items match with the elements in the EvidenceList)**, then:

```
evidence('broken_window').
evidence('bloodied_axe').
evidence('corpse').
evidence('suspect').

?- courtProof.
Enough Proof!
1true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just meant to write all this down as given to you, something like

```
broken_window.
bloodied_axe.
corpse.
arrested.

murder :- 
  body, burglary_site, 
  murder_tool, suspect.
```

and then make it work with

```
burglary_site :- 
  broken_door ; broken_window.
body :- corpse.
murder_tool :- 
  rifle ; bloodied_knife ; 
  bloodied_axe ; bullet.
suspect :- 
  arrested ; wounded ; killed.
```

And the query is :

```
?- murder.
```